# Trying to get list of VMs from Azure using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure

Very very new to Azure. Trying to use Python to get a list of virtual machines, however getting the following error.

```
The client 'AAAA' with object id 'AAAA' does not have authorization to perform action 
  'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read' over scope '/subscriptions/BBBB' or the scope is 
  invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

I have a "Pay-As-You-Go" subscription. I spun up one virtual machine. In my **Default Directory** I created an application using **App registration**. And then created an **Client credential**. This gives me all the UUID I need for `ClientSecretCredential` and `ComputeManagementClient` classes.

```
    credential = ClientSecretCredential(
        client_id="Application (client) ID",
        client_secret="Client credentials Secret",
        tenant_id="Default Directory Tenant ID"
    )
    compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential, "Pay-As-You-Go Subscription ID")
    vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list_all()
    for vm in vm_list: <--- Dies when attemping to get info
```

I'm trying to figure out where I need to assign the Virtual Machine roles. I can assign them to my user, however how and where can I assign the role to my application. I can see **App role**, and have tried to place "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read" in the **Value**, but pretty sure that not the correct value. I then added the **App role** to my **Api permissions**, and even granted it for the **Default Directory**. I've all tried to find the Virtual Machine API when I click "Add a permission" button.

I'm not sure if I have to do something in my subscription to get it cascade down the application or what.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

BTW: I see other people with the same problems, however I can get their solutions/possible solution to work for me.

Comment: I found this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-cli

I could create a role but in the UI could not figure out how to connect to my application in the scope of my subscription. CLI for the win!

Comment: You add the roles to applications just like to users, by going to "IAM" on the left menu. You could just assign the "Reader" role on a subscription or resource group scope. (if you read service principal, this is an application) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current#step-4-select-who-needs-access

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to figure out where I need to assign the Virtual Machine roles. I can assign them to my user, however how and where can I assign the role to my application.

You can assign roles using the Azure portal, Azure PowerShell, Azure CLI, Azure SDKs, or REST APIs.

**Through Azure Portal**

You can navigate to your resource >> Access control (IAM) >>Role assignments >> Add.

[image]

**Through Azure Powershell**

Below is the command that helps you to assign roles using `New-AzRoleAssignment`.

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId <objectId> `
-RoleDefinitionName <roleName> `
-Scope /subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourcegroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/<providerName>/<resourceType>/<resourceSubType>/<resourceName>
```

**REFERENCES:**
[Assign role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-steps#step-5-assign-role)